# Is a locally compact, locally metrizable space with countable extent and a dense metrizable subspace separable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally compact, locally metrizable space with countable extent, and suppose $X$ has a dense metrizable subspace. Is $X$ separable?

> **Definition:** A space $X$ has countable extent if every uncountable subset of $X$ has a limit point in $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $X=\omega_1,$ the set of all countable ordinals, with the order topology.

$\omega_1$ is locally compact and locally metrizable: for each point $\alpha\in\omega_1,$ the segment $[0,\alpha]$ is an open neighborhood of $\alpha$ which is compact and metrizable.

$\omega_1$ has countable extent: if $S$ is an uncountable subset of $\omega_1,$ then $\alpha=\min\{\xi\in\omega_1:\xi\cap S\text{ is infinite}\}$ is a limit point of $S$ in $\omega_1.$

$\omega_1$ has a dense metrizable subspace: the set $Y$ of all isolated points of $\omega_1$ is dense in $\omega_1;$ as a discrete space, $Y$ is metrizable.

$\omega_1$ is not separable: every countable subset of $\omega_1$ has a countable closure.